# Solr: top results when query (word/words) matches title, following when search matches descirption

Tags: search, solr, solrj

I have a Java application that uses Solr and SolrJ API for search.
I have an object with title and description and some other fields that have been imported into solr.
I'm trying to make the top responses be when search words in the query match the title, when there are no more matches in the title, the following results should be those that have matches in their description.

I have title and description fields set in schema.xml

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

I have tried boosting them in solrconfig.xml but I'm not sure it will give me the desired results and have not given so far.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: It depends on how you're searching and how you're indexing - include what you've tried and didn't give you the results you were looking for. If you're using the `edismax` query parser, you can give a weight for each field you're searching. So in your case, you could do `qf=title^10 description` to give a 10x boost to any hits in the `title` field. It wont _exactly_ match your requirement (i.e. "no more matches in title" - since there might be words that are unique in `description` but present in every single title (.. probably wouldn't be, but there's theory and then there's practice)

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh.
I'm using edismax parser and have boosted my query as follows:
`<str name="qf">
    title^10.0 description^5.0 search_source^0.1
   </str>`

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh.
I'm using edismax parser and have boosted my query as follows:
`<str name="qf">title^10.0 description^5.0</str>`
I discovered an issue with my sorting though, which produces false results
I'm now using sort=score desc, quality_weight desc as I have a quality_weight field indexed. This produces more or less desired results.

Comment: Yes, if you sort by a different field the score won't matter. In your case `quality_weight` will be used as a tiebreaker with identical scores (which might not be very many documents unless they're very similar). You'll want to tweak the boost factors to get a close to the behaviour you want as possible. You can also use the `quality_weight` field as a boost factor instead if that would be more in line with how you want the field to contribute.